# Delphi XE8 Printe VCL and DocumentProperties strange issue

Tags: windows, api, delphi, printing, delphi-xe8

I'm using the vcl.printers unit (delphi XE8) and I'm facing an error when "talking" to a printer.

I traced into the vcl.printers and found this code (written by EMB people):

```
if OpenPrinter(ADevice, FPrinterHandle, nil) then
 begin
  if DeviceMode = 0 then  // alloc new device mode block if one was not passed in
begin
  DeviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND,
    DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, nil, nil, 0));

  if DeviceMode <> 0 then
  begin
    DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);
    if DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, DevMode^,
      DevMode^, DM_OUT_BUFFER) < 0 then
    begin
      GlobalUnlock(DeviceMode);
      GlobalFree(DeviceMode);
      DeviceMode := 0;
      DevMode := nil;
    end
  end;
end;
if DeviceMode <> 0 then
  SetPrinterCapabilities(DevMode^.dmFields);
end;
```

The

```
DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, nil, nil, 0)
```

return the correct buffer size the first time (I haven't written it somewhere), then going thru the second execution time it returns  4294967295 bytes, indeed a -1 because declaration is wrong, but meanning an error.
As you can see the VCL code handle the errors very poorly since there is no error check !
But what error I have here and why ?

DocumentProperties lies in winspool.dll

To recover from it, I need to reboot the PC, but I cannot use this more than one time pass that is vey annoying for debug.
The printer is simply the "PDFcreator"

I tried with other PC and seems OK even if I run it many times.

I have also two laser network printers.

Thanks

Comment: There is an error check in both calls to `DocumentProperties` that you've posted. The first is the test for `DeviceMode <> 0`, which passes; the second is the test for `DocumentProperties() <> 0`. The first call asks for an allocation of memory of the proper size, the second passes in that block of memory for the function to populate. There is no error in the posted code; your understanding of their use is incorrect.

Comment: It seems DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, DevMode^,
      DevMode^, DM_OUT_BUFFER) is not correct, this is better I think  DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, DevMode^,
      NIL, DM_OUT_BUFFER)
This code is a library from Embarcadero, I haven't written it.

Comment: No, the code (as posted) is correct. It's worked for more than a decade, and works now in Windows 10 and XE 10 Seattle. It's also correct according to MSDN's documentation.

Comment: So why I'm getting a -1 from this function ?
I found this 
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107919

Comment: I don't know why you're getting anything, because you haven't posted any of your own code. All I can speak to is the code you've posted, and it's correctness based on the MSDN documentation and the fact I've used the Printer code you've included on all OS versions and Delphi versions since Delphi 1 without issue. What might be going wrong in your own code where you are *"talking"* (whatever that means) to the printer, I can't tell because I can't see your code. (And the QC report you linked indicated whatever issue that was was *fixed*. If there was indeed a fix, it will be in Seattle.)

Comment: "since Delphi 1 without issue" So If it does not work with me, this is just bad luck ?

Comment: It's impossible to say, **because you've not posted your code** or explained what *"talking"* to the printer means. My experience is that when a coder writes *I'm trying to do some [vague thing], and it doesn't work. It couldn't possibly be a problem with my code, so I'm not going to post it. There appears to be a bug in this [code that's worked for a decade or more from a well-known commercial library]. How do I fix this library bug?*, chances are very good that the problem is not in the library code. The problem is very likely in your own code that causes a problem in the library.

Comment: (continued) However, there's no way to determine which it is for sure because you *haven't explained clearly* what you're trying to do, you haven't *posted your code*, and you've merely said *It can't be my code, so it has to be this library.*. Please post a MCVE that clearly demonstrates the problem, and describe **specifically** what the code is supposed to do, and someone here can try and help figure it out. Saying *My code I won't show you isn't working, and the bug is somewhere else.* gives us nothing with which to help find a solution.

Comment: I posted the code above and this simply this. Opendriver works, and return a valid handle but then
    DeviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND,
    DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, nil, nil, 0));
returns an error !
I should give it a try to getlastErrormessage....

Comment: I give up. You're refusing to add the information I've asked for repeatedly, which is specifically what *"talking"* to the printer means and the code you're using to do so. I'm voting to close this until code *other than* the VCL source code is added to the post.

Comment: Do not give up :-) I love Delphi no problem :-) 
Talking => I try to use, by doing this : put a tprintdialog onto a form, and double click on it : nothing happens, and either do a PrinterSetupDialog.Execute and I could trace the code and found this issue inside the VCL of documentproperties.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in either Delphi 2007 or XE 10 Seattle. Tested by creating a new VCL forms application, dropping a `TPrinterSetupDialog` on the form, and double-clicking it. The expected printer setup dialog appears. This indicates the problem is on your system. So basic troubleshooting: 1) Do you have a printer installed? 2) Do you have a default printer selected? 3) In the IDE, switch to a code unit and do File-Print, and then Setup. Do you see a dialog? 4) Open another application and do a `Print->Setup` from it's menu.  See the printer setup dialog?

Comment: I have also wondered whether it comes from the system, from winspool.dll, that were  DocumentProperties is called. I have rebooted the PC, this is the same. All Delphi software I have written , and using the vcl.printer (3 others) has the same issue. But If I use another software written in C++/C# (I guess) that call the same printer selection, I have no issue, the window appears. So, by deduction, it means to me this vcl.printers code does something that Windows does not like.

Comment: I described **specific** troubleshooting tests, and you **ignored** every single one of them. Once again, if you're not going to listen and do what I ask, I'm through wasting time here. By deduction, you've demonstrated absolutely nothing that indicates it's a VCL.Printers problem, and you've failed to help determine what the real problem is by ignoring basic troubleshooting attempts. The fact that I can't reproduce it in two separate (and quite different) Delphi versions is evidence to show the problem is localized to your system. Your unwillingness to do basic testing is unacceptable.

Comment: You do not seem to understand me... please keep calm and take it easy.
1) Do you have a printer installed?
Yes off course, I have seven of them

 2) Do you have a default printer selected? 
Yes, and changed the default printer many times


3) In the IDE, switch to a code unit and do File-Print, and then Setup. Do you see a dialog?
No, nothing come because of this error badly handled in Vcl.printers.pas


 4) Open another application and do a Print->Setup from it's menu. See the printer setup dialog?
Yes of course

Comment: I understand you clearly. You've got a problem on your system that you're insisting is a bug in the Printers unit, while you've failed to do anything to eliminate the actual cause of the problem on your system. You've also continually ignored requests to provide additional information or to do basic diagnostic steps to try and isolate the issue, and then you protest because I'm getting frustrated with your lack of cooperation. What's the point in trying to help you when you're going to ignore every attempt to do so? You've made up your mind, and nothing I say is going to change it.

Comment: So my only remaining suggestion is to use the debugger to figure out what's happening in the code in Printers.pas. (You probably won't listen anyway.) Examine exact content of variables that are being used both before and after the call to `DocumentProperties` to see what's happening. Use the *Evaluate/Modify* debug window to examine (and if necessary change) the variables to try to identify the problem Once you've run out of things to try and come to the realization that the problem isn't there, you can then start trying to figure out where it's really located. Good luck.

Comment: Ken, I have written a software that has 1.1 million line code in Delphi, doing it since 1992, so I'm not a beginner... so please change the way you are talking to peope you do not know. 
"you protest because I'm getting frustrated with your lack of cooperation" ?? you kidding me... :-))
Anyway, I did that already trace and I went into the code I have posted above inside VCL.Printers.pas. 
ADevice and FPrinterHandle seems "OK", ie, returns valid numbers. But not Documentproperties

Comment: My system ca be corrupted and winspool.dll can be behaving in an odd fashion, but it works flawlessly with other software, and from what I can see in the web, there is some topics like this and people dealing with the same issue.

Comment: *in Delphi, doing it since 1992*. Interesting, since Delphi 1.0 wasn't released until 1996. You must be *really* experienced in order to write that many lines of code in a language and IDE that didn't exist until 4 years later. And certainly, since no one else started using it until it was released, you should be much more experienced and therefore more capable of actually debugging the code than anyone here. What do you need mere amateurs like us for?

Comment: 1992 Started with Borland DOS tools, and moved to Delphi in 1996 Ok, Mr Police officer ?
Ken White, you are not helping in anything here.. just been very arrogant.
So why not saying bye bye to you ?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I did have the same problem with two customers. I did track it down to printers unit (printers.pas) Kind of hard to track it down without debugger on a distant computer in other part of my country.

Ok.. but I did track it all the way down to this line:

DeviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties (0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, StubDevMode, StubDevMode, 0)); in the function SetPrinter in the unit PRINTERS.PAS

When I did broke it up into two lines, i.e. call to DocumentProperties first and store the value in integer variable and then check the value and only then call Globalalloc if the value is greater than 0 and kind of debugged it with stored values in debug file the error was truly in the DocumentProperties function from SPOOL.DLL if I remember correctly. This function returned -1 as size for the device, but only with this customer on one computer (he is using 4 or 5 with my program)

Of all my customers (close to 200 clients) I have had this issue on two computers. The other one fixed it kind of itself.. I didn't know how it did get fixed. The later one I was trying to fix just a couple of minutes ago. In the end I found a solution. I did fix this customer with simple change of **shortcut**. I began to use the automatic fix for compatibility in Windows 10 and then ran the button "test program" and it worked.. No error choosing printers or using it's propertis. Ok.. Then I tried again with the shortcut alone.. aarrgg..  error returned.. but then, aha.. I thought to myself "this has to connects to how Windows is running this program" and changed how Windows 10 ran the program as check "run as administrator" to uncheck.

**And no problem.**

On almost every compture with Windows 10 I do check "Run as Administrator" with no problems. I think there was a update or some issues with spool.dll that connects these dots.

ps. *If you google this behavior with Delphi DocumentProperties problems, then you will find out this is known problem.. some say connected to x86 and x64 mode, but I found this out.*